# Possible to replace a ButtonField with an image in a GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, buttonfield

I have a GridView which has a delete link to delete a record. I have created a DeleteButtonField class but I want to replace the text with an image (an icon). Is this possible? Here's my GridView:

```
<asp:GridView 
    ID="GridView1" 
    runat="server"
    <.. removed dome properties ..> 
    >
    <Columns>
    <CustomControls:DeleteButtonField ConfirmText="Delete this record?" /> 
    <.. other columns ..>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and here's my DeleteButtonField class:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace CustomControls
{
    public class DeleteButtonField : ButtonField
    {
        private string _confirmText = "Delete this record?";

        public string ConfirmText
        {
            get { return _confirmText; }
            set { _confirmText = value; }
        }

        public DeleteButtonField()
        {
            this.CommandName = "Delete";
            this.Text = "Delete";
            this.ImageUrl = "App_GlobalResources/Del.png";   // doesn't work
        }

        public override void InitializeCell(DataControlFieldCell cell, DataControlCellType cellType, DataControlRowState rowState, int rowIndex)
        {
            base.InitializeCell(cell, cellType, rowState, rowIndex);
            if (cellType == DataControlCellType.DataCell)
            {
                WebControl button = (WebControl)cell.Controls[0];
                button.Attributes["onclick"] = String.Format("return confirm('{0}');", _confirmText);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is this possible? As you can see I add the following code to my DeleteButtonField.cs class but it had no effect: `this.ImageUrl = "App_GlobalResources/Del.png";`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let's trash the idea of overriding the button field and go with a simple template field.  It will handle the post backs correctly and raise the GridView's (RowCommand & RowDeleting) events.  Hope this helps! =)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;


namespace MyExample.Web
{
    public class MyDeleteButtonField : TemplateField
    {
        #region Properties

        private string _ConfirmText = "Delete Me?";
        public string ConfirmText
        {
            get { return _ConfirmText; }
            set { _ConfirmText = value; }
        }

        private string _ImageUrl = "~/Assets/Images/Buttons/flip.png";
        public string ImageUrl
        {
            get { return _ImageUrl; }
            set { _ImageUrl = value; }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        public override bool Initialize(bool sortingEnabled, System.Web.UI.Control control)
        {
            base.ItemTemplate = new MyTemplate(this.ConfirmText, this.ImageUrl);
            return base.Initialize(sortingEnabled, control);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Template

        public class MyTemplate : ITemplate
        {
            private string _ConfirmText;
            private string _ImageUrl;

            public MyTemplate(string confirmText, string imageUrl)
            {
                _ConfirmText = confirmText;
                _ImageUrl = imageUrl;
            }

            void ITemplate.InstantiateIn(Control container)
            {
                ImageButton bt = new ImageButton();
                bt.CommandName = "Delete";
                bt.ImageUrl = _ImageUrl;
                bt.ImageAlign = ImageAlign.AbsMiddle;
                bt.AlternateText = "Delete Me";
                bt.OnClientClick = String.Format("return confirm('{0}');", _ConfirmText);
                container.Controls.Add(bt);

            }
        }

        #endregion

    }
}
```

Comment: @Brian, I have a problem. The records don't get deleted now when I click on the image. Do you know what might have gone wrong?

Comment: Mark, take a look at the code above.  Should get you working now.  I should of stuck to my guns as I originally was going to write a TemplateField example for you.  It handles things better (postbacks, etc). :)

Comment: @Brian, thanks for that. When I run this the ASP.NET Development web server crashes!

Comment: Interesting, I ran this on my side w/ .NET 4, VS2010 w/ dev web server and had no issues.  Make sure your code isn't doing a circular ref like adding same controls again and again.   Put some breaks in and give it a debug.   Send me personal message and I'll send you my test project.

Comment: @Brian - SO doesn't support private messaging. I will put some breaks in and see what is happening.

Comment: @Brian - yes it looks like there's an infinite loop, but I don't know why. I get this error without any breaks: `An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`. The exception occurs when trying to open a connection to get data to fill one of my GridViews. Very confused.

Answer (score 1):

Mark, I think you're custom class is very, very close. For the `ButtonField` class to show an image you need to both specify the `ImageUrl` property *and* set the `ButtonType` property to `ButtonType.Image`.

Try updating your `DeleteButtonField` class's constructor to:

```
public DeleteButtonField()
{
    this.CommandName = "Delete";
    this.Text = "Delete";
    this.ImageUrl = "App_GlobalResources/Del.png";
    this.ButtonType = ButtonType.Button;
}
```

Alternatively, you could specify these settings through the declarative syntax in the `.aspx` page:

```
<CustomControls:DeleteButtonField ConfirmText="Delete this record?" ImageUrl='...' ButtonType="Image" />
```

Happy Programming!

Comment: Scott I get the same problem, the delete does not get sent to the database. I don't think the DeleteMethod gets called. Any further ideas?

Comment: @Mark: Your initial question stated that the Delete button image was not showing. But now your question seems a bit different - namely, that the delete isn't working. So is the delete button image now showing with my answer?

Comment: indeed the button image is showing, but the delete does not actually delete anything. Without the image the delete works. A bit weird, but there we are.

Comment: @Mark: I'd suggest accepting this answer for this question and then creating a new question for your new one.